# Spring Caching not working with Memcached

Tags: spring, caching, memcached, spring-cache, spymemcached

I'm trying to get my web application running with REST API features and caching using Memcached.

Spring does not throw an error while I deploy the application. But the caching does not work. I have used spymemcached Java client along with Spring caching.
Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?
This is a snippet of my root context

```
    <cache:annotation-driven />
<bean class="net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="serverList" type="java.util.List" />
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.restdemo.cache" />

<util:list id="serverList" value-type="java.net.InetSocketAddress">
    <bean class="java.net.InetSocketAddress">
        <constructor-arg value="127.0.0.1" type="java.lang.String" />
        <constructor-arg value="11211" type="int" />
    </bean>
</util:list>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean name="coursesCache" class="com.restdemo.cache.Memcache">
            </bean>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my implementation of the Cache interface

```
public class Memcache implements Cache {

@Autowired
MemcachedClient cache;

private final String name = "";

public void clear() {
    cache.flush();

}

public void evict(Object key) {
    this.cache.delete(key.toString());

}

public ValueWrapper get(Object key) {
    Object value = null;
    try {
        value = cache.get(key.toString());
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new SimpleValueWrapper(value);
}

public <T> T get(Object arg0, Class<T> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public <T> T get(Object arg0, Callable<T> arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Object getNativeCache() {
    return cache;
}

public void put(Object key, Object value) {
    cache.set(key.toString(), 7 * 24 * 3600, value);

}

public ValueWrapper putIfAbsent(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

I have used the Cacheable annotation in my RestController as follows-

```
@GetMapping("/courses")
@Cacheable("coursesCache")
public List<Course> getCourses() {
    return courseDAO.getAllCourses();
}
```

I'm sure that the Memcached client is getting created just fine. Else I was getting the error when the root context beans were created. But then caching isn't working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is already available solution that integrates memcached (spymemcached or xmemcached) with Spring Cache abstraction: [Simple Spring Memcached](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached). Consider using it.